# pull specific data from mysql database into thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puNVa.png)

I need to pull only the specific data from table 1 which are connected to the data in table 2. for example :

Lets say in "menu" table I have 2 rows - "Pizza" and "Fries"
and in "Ingredients table" I have 3 rows - "Cheese" , "Potatoes", "Sauce"

"Pizza" is connected to "Cheese" and "Sauce" with foreign keys from Third Table and "Fries" is connected to "Potato", now I want to show only the Data from "menu" table and "Ingredients" table which are connected to each other.

e.g:

Pizza - "Cheese", "Sauce"

Fries - "Potato"

so far I can only list the data (all the data) from both tables, I can't choose which data is shown.

Thymeleaf :

```
        <tr th:each="menu : ${menuList}">
        <td th:text="${menu.name}"></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/foodDescription}" th:text="Description">Description</a></td>
        <td th:each="ing : ${ingredientList}">
            <ul>
                <li th:text = ${ing.ingredientName}></li>
                <!-- Here I only want to display ingredientName and description which 
                are connected to the specific ${menu.name} -->
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Controller :

```
    @Controller
    public class MyController{

    @Autowired
    MenuRepository menuRepository;

    @Autowired
    IngredientRepository ingredientRepository;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    private String hello(){
        return "hello-page";
    }

    @GetMapping("/recipeList")
    public String listPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("menuList",menuRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("ingredientList", ingredientRepository.findAll());
        return "list-page";
    }
```

Menu.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // Mapping To second table
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "menu_ingredient",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
    private List<Ingredients> ingredient = new ArrayList<>();
// Constructor/Getter/Setter/ToString
```

Ingredient.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredients")
public class Ingredients {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ingredient")
    private String ingredientName;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String ingredientDescription;
```

Comment: Consider iterating over the `List<Ingredients>` which is already included in a `Menu` instance.  This will avoid having to do any filtering within the template.  Side bar:  the class names are somewhat confusing - `Ingredients` is plural but really represents a single ingredient. `Menu` (as a physical object) suggests a container of multiple items which could be ordered, e.g., `MenuItem` might be a better name.  Then a `Menu` could contain a `List<MenuItem> menuItems` and a `MenuItem` could contain a `List<Ingredient> ingredients`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Menu` has a association with `Ingredients`, it will contain linked ingredients. You need not fetch `Ingredients` separately.

```
<tr th:each="menu : ${menuList}">
    <td th:text="${menu.name}"></td>
    <td><a th:href="@{/foodDescription}" th:text="Description">Description</a></td>
    <td th:each="ing : ${menu.ingredient}"> <!-- I have only modified here -->
        <ul>
            <li th:text = ${ing.ingredientName}></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
```

Comment: Oh I get it , I was giving thymeleaf the whole list of "ingredients" when I needed to give the already associated list which I had in "menu" entity. So cool, thanks :)